# Gerrit trackingid not working

Tags: gerrit

According to [this section](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/config-gerrit.html#_a_id_trackingid_a_section_trackingid), I have created the following entries in the `gerrrit.config` file:

```
[trackingid "jira-issue"]
    footer = Issue:
    match = "\\[PROJECT-\\d+\\]"
    system = JIRA
```

When I commit a new patchset (or a new change) with the following commit message, the tracking id is not created.

```
[PROJECT-123] My commit message

Change-Id: Ia5b58dda57ef12632075738d1301f2e143066d45
```

I have checked the `tracking_ids` table in database and it's empty. Filtering changes with `tr:PROJECT-123` have no results. What can be wrong?

I have restarted Gerrit after making the configuration change. Gerrit v2.8.

Comment: Is there any particular use of system attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the tracking ID needs to go in the footer of the commit message, using the `footer` argument as its name.  In your case:

```
My commit message

Change-Id: Ia5b58dda57ef12632075738d1301f2e143066d45
Issue: [PROJECT-123]
```

The order of the `name: value` pairs in the footer doesn't matter - they just must all be in one paragraph (no blank lines between items).

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I see what "tagged footer" means.

Answer (score 2):

If it does work in the body of the commit message, then it is probably this issue: [Support TrackingIds in subject as well as footer](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=849).